# jQuery "split" options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to sort some dates.

Thats the html div:

```
<div class="the_date">30/11/2015, 19:24</div>
```

Thats the part of jQuery:

```
var date1 = $(a).find(".the_date").text();
  date1 = date1.split('/');
  date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0], date1[3], date1[4]);
```

My problem: it will only works if the date looks like this (because of the split option):

```
<div class="the_date">30/11/2015/19/24</div>
```

Is there a way to split in different ways? For example first "/", if not exist "," if not exist ":"? Or is that a bad way?

Comment: Look at http://momentjs.com/ -- failing that, learn about regular expressions, which will do what you need.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date1 = date1.split(/\/|,|:/g);
```

Comment: @epascarello the Date constructor doesn't mind the space.  But I do like your solution better :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry about matching all of the different separators. Just match the numbers with the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `\d+`:

```
"30/11/2015, 19:24".match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

Note: The `.map(Number)` is not needed, it is just a neat way to convert the array of strings to numbers.

Result with: `[30, 11, 2015, 19, 24]`
Result without: `["30", "11", "2015", "19", "24"]`

Comment: Thx for support! Can you explain it a bit more - I am not so good at jQuery, sry!

Comment: Your way looks professionell but spozuns way is more what I was looking for - but thx!

Comment: And his has an issue with split as I said in my comment on that answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `split` method accepts regular expressions as an argument to split by.

Here's some examples:

```js
var str = '30/11/2015, 19:24';
var parts = str.split(/[\/,: ]+/); // split by a specific set of characters
console.log(parts);
// ["30", "11", "2015", "19", "24"]
```

```js
var str = '30/11/2015, 19:24';
var parts = str.split(/\D+/); // split by all non-digit characters
console.log(parts);
// ["30", "11", "2015", "19", "24"]
```